# Python - Can't figure out syntax of tcp/udp client using socket module

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp, client-server

I have been trying to make a client-server system following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiVVYfgDolU&t=384s) and for some reason when testing it on two different computers the two computers won't connect.

Both the UDP and the TCP code have failed, and I suspect it's because I can't figure out which IP goes to where.

Code for host:

```
import socket

def main():
    host = 'ip.ip.ip.ip'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connection from: " + str(addr))

    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print("From connected user: " + str(data))
        data = str(data).upper()
        print("Sending " + str(data))
        c.send(data)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Code for client:

```
import socket

def main():
    host = 'ip.ip.ip.ip'
    port = 5000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    message = raw_input("-> ")
    while message != 'q':
        s.send(message)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print("Recived from server: " + str(data))
        message = raw_input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If this really the indentation you have in your files which you show here? If this is the case I recommend to watch the tutorial again and adjust your indentation to the one which is shown in the tutorial. Proper indentation is essential in Python since it defines program logic.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich When testing on the same computer like in the video, it worked; I just cant figure out which IP goes to where (ipv4, ipv6 etc)

Comment: *I just cant figure out which IP goes to where* - It should be the same IP for both sides, i.e. the public (client visible) IP address of the server. If client and server are both on the same system you can use localhost 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I don't get what do you mean, can you send an example?

Comment: Example of what - of the IP address your machine has? I have no idea what you specific machine has. But you can find out with [ipconfig](https://www.lifewire.com/ip-config-818377) on Windows or `ifconfig` on Linux. But this is actually not a programming problem (which means probably off-topic here) but requires basic understanding of networks.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, What I ment was where to put the client's IP and where to put the server's IP...

Comment: To cite myself: *"It should be the same IP for both sides, i.e. the public (client visible) IP address of the server."*. In other words: *"where to put the client's IP"* - nowhere, *"where to put the server's IP"* - on both sides.

Comment: Usually, you do not specify an IP address on the server side. Just provide an empty string (`host = ""`) for the address in the `bind` call. This causes the server to accept a connection on any server interface. On the  client side, the `connect` address to use is the IP address of the server: e.g. `host = 192.168.0.5` in the client code (replace that address with what you get from running `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` on the server machine per @SteffenUllrich comment).

Comment: @GilHamilton Sorry about the delay, thank you so much, it is now working :)